# How can I write a single method instead of two methods that has a single Boolean expression differences

Tags: c#, func

Let's say I have two methods.
One checks registry key with exact match and one checks vague registry key check.

```
public bool exactCheck(string name)
{
  // something common
  for(...)
  {
    string displayName = ... subkey get common code ...
    if (name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
    {
      // something more common
    }
  }
  // more common
}

public bool vagueCheck(string name)
{
  // something common
  for(...)
  {
    string displayName = ... subkey get common code ...
    if (displayName.IndexOf(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
      // something more common
    }
  }
  // more common
}
```

As you can see above, the only differences are the boolean in this method.
Obviously I could have used Func delegate such as `Func<string, string, bool>` **if I did not have to figure out `displayName` multiple times inside this method**.

Now I could add a bool that checks if it's exact or vague and have the if statement inside the single method like below.

```
public bool exact(string name, string displayName)
public bool vague(string name, string displayName)

public bool exactOrVagueCheck(string name, bool isExact)
{
  // ...
  for(...)
  {
    string displayName = ... subkey get common code ...
    if ((isExact && exact(name, displayName)) || (!isExact && vague(name, displayName)))
    {
      // ...
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

But this does not feel elegant at all.
Is there any better way to achieve what I would like to achieve?

Comment: This question is too broad. There are many possible ways to improve your code. However, you need to make some attempt first, and then constrain your question to whatever _specific_ issue you run into (if any). If/when you get to that point and have a suitable question, be sure to provide a good [mcve] showing _exactly_ what the problem is, with a clear, detailed explanation of what it is precisely you're unable to figure out.

Comment: Very opinion-based question... Here is mine - use `Func<string, string, bool>` as parameter to perform whole check (instead of passing bool that pick between two)

Comment: What do you mean by "I could have used Func delegate such as `Func<string, string, bool>` if I did not have to figure out displayName multiple times inside this method."? Why does figuring out the displayName affect your ability to use the delegate?

Comment: Alexei means you should call `generalcheck(displayname=>displayName.IndexOf(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)`, I shortened it to Func<string, bool>

Comment: _"I do wish to learn how I could code better"_ -- an admirable goal. _"what could I have asked better that would not trigger these flags, yet I may be able to know better way to do things than what I know?"_ -- for better or worse, Stack Overflow isn't the place _"to know better way to do things"_. In _some_ cases, you may find codereview.stackexchange.com helpful. But be sure to read their help pages first. And do so here as well. The [ask] and [mcve] pages are particularly useful. Bottom line: SO is for _specific problems_, not open-ended "how can I do better?" questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for redirecting me to codereview. I did not know the existence of it. stackexchange always impresses me with amount of service that they have. I will be careful from next time on.

Comment: Consider also softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. That site is even more accommodating of open-ended "best practices" type questions. Again, read their help to make sure you stay on-topic, but you may find that's another good place to find help improving your skills as a programmer.

Comment: Thanks again for another great suggestions. I have made account with both of them and will read their helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use a delegate.

```
private bool Check(string name, Func<string, string, bool> compareNames)
{
  // ...
  for(...)
  {
    string displayName = ... subkey get common code ...
    if (compareNames(name, displayName))
    {
      // ...
    }
  }
  // ...
}

public bool ExactCheck(string name) => Check(
    (name, displayName) => name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
);

public bool VagueCheck(string name) => Check(
    (name, displayName) => displayName.IndexOf(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
);
```